# How to convert a dataset in str format (imported from clipboard) to a python data frame?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, clipboard

I ran the following query:

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
df= win32clipboard.GetClipboardData().rstrip()
print(df)
```

When I want to see `df`, it looks like this:

```
\tDeal Type\tDeal #\tTrade Date\tValue Date\tTr\tCustomer\tPay Ccy\tPay Amount\tRec Ccy\tRec Amount\tRate\tUser Comments\tTime Option Start\t\r\n15\tFX\t2021062306\t23 Jun 2021\t24 Jun 2021\tEDL\txxx xxx\tCAD\t18,341.45\tUSD\t14,950.28\t1.2268300\t\t\t\r\n116\tFX\t2021021111\t11 Feb 2021\t30 Jul 2021\tAIA\txxx xxx xxxx\tUSD\t250,000.00\tCAD\t318,400.00\t1.2736000\t\t\t\r\n138\t
```

How can I convert the `df` into an actual data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
from io import StringIO

s = """\tDeal Type\tDeal #\tTrade Date\tValue Date\tTr\tCustomer\tPay Ccy\tPay Amount\tRec Ccy\tRec Amount\tRate\tUser Comments\tTime Option Start\t\r\n15\tFX\t2021062306\t23 Jun 2021\t24 Jun 2021\tEDL\txxx xxx\tCAD\t18,341.45\tUSD\t14,950.28\t1.2268300\t\t\t\r\n116\tFX\t2021021111\t11 Feb 2021\t30 Jul 2021\tAIA\txxx xxx xxxx\tUSD\t250,000.00\tCAD\t318,400.00\t1.2736000\t\t\t\r\n138\t"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=r"\t", engine="python", dtype=str)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Deal Type Deal #  Trade Date   Value Date           Tr Customer       Pay Ccy Pay Amount     Rec Ccy Rec Amount        Rate User Comments Time Option Start
0        15     FX  2021062306  23 Jun 2021  24 Jun 2021      EDL       xxx xxx        CAD   18,341.45        USD   14,950.28     1.2268300              None
1       116     FX  2021021111  11 Feb 2021  30 Jul 2021      AIA  xxx xxx xxxx        USD  250,000.00        CAD  318,400.00     1.2736000              None
2       138   None        None         None         None     None          None       None        None       None        None          None              None
```